# Unsuccessful Options Request to my Rest API over HTTPS

Tags: api, angular, http, ssl, https

I have hosted a client (build in angular2) and an API (build in PHP, Zend Framework 1) over an apache server. I have added virtual hosts (both for the client and the API) which redirects `http` requests to `https`. The `SSL` virtual host contains security certificate and key of some other website.

When I route to a client URL, the browser alerts about `insecure connection` and has error code: `Error code: SEC_ERROR_CERT_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM_DISABLED` and asks if I want to add an exception, I accept that and add the URL as an exception, after this a request is made to an API URL, the browser first makes an `OPTIONS` request which returns an empty response and no further requests are made. I get an error in console for `unhandled promise rejection`, probably that is because the returned response(which is nothing) is not handled properly in my application.

I believe even the API URL should be added as an exception to the browser so when I directly enter an API URL in the URL bar, again the browser asks If I want to add an exception, I accept that and my application works fine.

Question: Is there some way by which I can get past adding the API URL as an exception / or as an exception manually? Or is there some other way to handle this?
Please note: I don't have a valid certificate now.

Comment: Is that the only error? Is there not also one mentioning a missing access control allow origin header?

Comment: Yes, currently that is the only error I am getting, probably because I have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*`